# How to check if the file really exists in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

In the loop, I am using the following code to check that the file really exists or not

```
<?php 
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();   
    $explode = explode('/', $url);
    $url = trim('../../'.basename(wp_get_upload_dir()['basedir']).wp_get_upload_dir()['subdir'].'/'.end($explode));
    echo $url;
    if( file_exists($url)) {
        $url = $url;
    } else {
        $url = '';
    }
} else {
    $url = get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/blog/layout-1/blog-thumbnail-1.jpg';
}                                          
?>
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="blog thumb">
```

that echo `$url` is printing this url:

> ../../uploads/2019/07/5e026bb1-b58b-3df0-ae5f-2acd7d808ff3.jpg

but now it's not working. I can't determine that the `$url` file really exists or not.

**Updated:**

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {                                                
    $url            = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
    $explode        = explode('/', $url);
    $upload_dir     = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_path    = $upload_dir['path'];
    $url            = $upload_path . '/' . end($explode);

    if(file_exists($url)) {
        $url = get_the_post_thumbnail('blog-thumb');
    } else {
        $url = get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/blog/layout-1/blog-thumbnail-1.jpg';
    }
} else {
    $url = get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/blog/layout-1/blog-thumbnail-1.jpg';
}                                                                                       
?>
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="blog thumb">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try code below

```
$url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();

$explode = explode('/', $url);
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_path = $upload_dir['path'];

$url = $upload_path . '/' . end($explode);

var_dump(file_exists($url));die;
```

Please, check your file in folder carefully.

Comment: it's return `true`

Comment: I have updated the question. Now it's showing 1 image correctly and 2 images showing like that : `<img src="unknown" alt="blog thumb">`

Comment: plz read more wordpress function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/
`get_the_post_thumbnail` don't return a url of the image